# Move derivative inside summation for convergent series

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I want to show $d/dt\sum_{k=1} ^\infty(At)^k/k! =  \sum_{k=1} ^∞ d/dt(At)^k/k!$
Obviously, $(At)^k/k!$ is convergent, but I don't know how to show that I can move the derivative inside the summation.
I can compute entry by entry, but I guess this is not what I am supposed to do...

Comment: Yes, but I want to show why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use that $\frac{d}{dx} (f(x)+g(x)) = \frac{d}{dx} f(x)+\frac{d}{dx} g(x)$ and evaluate the sum term by term. This would be an induction type proof.

I suppose you may still wonder if you can divide the series up that way. If the series is universally convergent then you can rearrange the sum in any way without issue.